# Сумма элементов массива слева и справа от конкретного индекса

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как найти номер элемента в массиве, на котором сумма всех остальных чисел слева и справа от него - одинаковая?

Comment: (возможно автор имел в виду просто нахождение центрального элемента в массиве). В таком случае `var index = Math.floor(array.length / 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы найти нужный индекс, я перебираю весь массив, вычисляю `массив элементов слева` и `массив элемента справа` от текущего индекса. После чего сравниваю суммы элементов этих двух массивов и при их тождестве сохраняю в `neededIndex`.

```
const arr = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let neededIndex = -1;

const getArrSum = array => array.reduce((acc, currValue) => acc + currValue, 0);

arr.map((val, currentIndex) => {
  const arrLeft = arr.slice(0, currentIndex);
  const arrRight = arr.slice(Math.min(arr.length - 1, currentIndex + 1));

  if (getArrSum(arrLeft) === getArrSum(arrRight)) {
    neededIndex = currentIndex;
  }
});

if (neededIndex >= 0 ) {
  console.log(`Искомый индекс: ${neededIndex}`);
} else {
  console.log('Такого индекса не найдено');
}
```

Замечу, что если в `neededIndex` лежит `-1`(именно это значение мы положили в начале), то это означает, что такого индекса нет.